# DocumentDb and how to create folder?

Tags: directory, azure-cosmosdb

New to documentdb and I am trying to determine the best way to store documents.  We are uploading documents every 15 minutes and I need to keep them as easily separated by upload as possible.  At first glance, I thought I could have a database and a collection for each upload.  Then, I discovered you can only have 3 collections per database.  This leaves me with either adding a naming convention or trying to use folders and paths.  According to the same source (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-limits/), we are limited to 100 paths per collection.  This leaves folders.  I have been looking, but I haven't found anything concrete on creating folders within a collection.  The object API doesn't have an obvious add/create method.

Is this possible?  If so, are we limited to how many (assuming I stay within the allowed collection/database size)?

Comment: What's a document in your case? A document of JSON data or something like a Word document? For the second one you could have a look at [attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn782196.aspx). Nevertheless, why do you want to create a new collection for every document? The limit of the path is related to indexes you could use.

Comment: I am looking for an logical aggregation as this time next year, there will be a lot of documents.   We are storing JSON results.  As it stands now, I can dump the result into a collection and an id gets generated.  Simple queries work, but I was hoping to have a grouping by month/year or some other logical aggregator so we didn't have to query the entire pile of documents.  However, this is the course I seem to have open to me.  I am exploring how complicated/fast queries can be using the document db studio (https://studiodocumentdb.codeplex.com/).  A folder creation option would fit nice :)

Comment: For anyone else finding this post, what we ended up doing was just dumping everything into one collection.  The azure documentdb query language (i.e. sql like) seems robust enough to handle detailed queries.  Though I am not sure what the efficiency will be like once we have a ton of documents in there.

Comment: @ProgramTheWorld - if you've found a solution and expect people to see it in the future, you should post it as an *answer*, not as a *comment.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a sequential naming convention and create a range index on the collection indexing policy. In this way, if you need to retrieve a range of documents, you can do it in this way, which will leverage the indexing capabilities of docdb efficiently.

As a recommendation, you can examine the charge response header on the requests you fire off during your tests. This allows you to gauge how efficient your setup is (how stringent it is against the Db, which will translate into your cost structure for the service)

Comment: I am going to give Luis credit as this is the closest it appears you can get to some sort of aggregation grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the comment.  What we ended up doing was just dumping everything into one collection. The azure documentdb query language (i.e. sql like) seems robust enough to handle detailed queries. Though I am not sure what the efficiency will be like once we have a ton of documents in there.